# Create an expandable group in a property grid?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, user-controls

> SCENARIO

I've sub-classed a `ListBox` and I've added color properties for when my control is **Enabled**, **Disabled**, or in **ReadOnly** mode:

[image]

> QUESTION

In C# or VB.Net, what I need to do to organize the properties in the property grid into expandable groups with this structure?:

```
[+] State Enabled

  [+] Selected Item
      · BackColor
      · ForeColor

  [+] Unselected Item
      · BackColor
      · ForeColor
```

This is a visual example taken from a `Krypton` lib user control that demonstrates what I would like to mimic:

[image]

> UPDATE

I think that in this url is explained all the necessary about property grids:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2764/Using-PropertyGrid-Part-I

But it is focused to do it with form which has a **Load** event, I still can't understand how to implement that example in my user control because If I create a sub-class to customize the property grid like in that example then I can't acces to my control's base class.

My code has a simple structure like this:

```
Public Class ElektroListBox : Inherits ListBox

    <Category("Appearance")>
    <Description("The BackColor to paint the selected item when the control is enabled.")>
    Public Property StateEnabledItemSelectedBackColor As Color
        Get
            Return Me.stateEnabledItemSelectedBackColor1
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Color)
            Me.stateEnabledItemSelectedBackColor1  = value
            Me.Invalidate(invalidateChildren:=False)
        End Set
    End Property

    Private stateEnabledItemSelectedBackColor1 As Color = Color.Red

End Class
```

Comment: That is not simply a cosmetic thing. First, it relies on a Type and you probably have them defined As Color. Second, if the Type is a standard one, such as Size or Point, VS will do it automatically (Define a new prop `FooBar As Point` and see). Otherwise you may have to write your own UITypeEditor and/or TypeConverter. (note how the ones in the linked article are all standard types: Location, Font. Size).  Sometimes, you can provide enough information in a TypeConverter for it to work automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is to structure your properties into classes. Then you need to create a custom [type converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for each class so it becomes serializable. However, there's an easier way to achieve this; inherit [Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. Here's a simple example.

```vb
Public Class UIListBox
    Inherits ListBox

    Public Sub New()
        Me.m_stateDisabled = New ItemLayout(Me)
        Me.m_stateEnabled = New ItemLayout(Me)
        Me.m_stateReadOnly = New ItemLayout(Me)
    End Sub

    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
    Public ReadOnly Property StateDisabled() As ItemLayout
        Get
            Return Me.m_stateDisabled
        End Get
    End Property

    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
    Public ReadOnly Property StateEnabled() As ItemLayout
        Get
            Return Me.m_stateEnabled
        End Get
    End Property

    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
    Public ReadOnly Property StateReadOnly() As ItemLayout
        Get
            Return Me.m_stateReadOnly
        End Get
    End Property

    Friend Sub NotifyStateChanged(source As ItemLayoutColors, propertyName As String)
        Me.Invalidate()
        Debug.WriteLine("UIListBox: State changed.")
    End Sub

    Private m_stateDisabled As ItemLayout
    Private m_stateEnabled As ItemLayout
    Private m_stateReadOnly As ItemLayout

End Class

<ToolboxItem(False)>
Public Class ItemLayout
    Inherits Component

    Public Sub New(listBox As UIListBox)
        Me.m_listBox = listBox
        Me.m_background = New ItemLayoutColors(Me)
        Me.m_foreground = New ItemLayoutColors(Me)
    End Sub

    Friend ReadOnly Property ListBox() As UIListBox
        Get
            Return Me.m_listBox
        End Get
    End Property

    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
    Public ReadOnly Property Background() As ItemLayoutColors
        Get
            Return Me.m_background
        End Get
    End Property

    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
    Public ReadOnly Property Foreground() As ItemLayoutColors
        Get
            Return Me.m_foreground
        End Get
    End Property

    Private m_background As ItemLayoutColors
    Private m_foreground As ItemLayoutColors
    Private m_listBox As UIListBox

End Class

<ToolboxItem(False)>
Public Class ItemLayoutColors
    Inherits Component

    Public Sub New(layout As ItemLayout)
        If (layout Is Nothing) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("layout")
        Me.m_layout = layout
    End Sub

    Friend ReadOnly Property Layout() As ItemLayout
        Get
            Return Me.m_layout
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property Selected() As Color
        Get
            Return Me.m_selected
        End Get
        Set(value As Color)
            If (value <> Me.m_selected) Then
                Me.m_selected = value
                Me.Layout.ListBox.NotifyStateChanged(Me, "Selected")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Unselected() As Color
        Get
            Return Me.m_unselected
        End Get
        Set(value As Color)
            If (value <> Me.m_unselected) Then
                Me.m_unselected = value
                Me.Layout.ListBox.NotifyStateChanged(Me, "Unselected")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Function ShouldSerializeSelected() As Boolean
        Return (Me.Selected <> Color.Empty)
    End Function

    Private Function ShouldSerializeUnselected() As Boolean
        Return (Me.Unselected <> Color.Empty)
    End Function

    Private m_selected As Color
    Private m_unselected As Color
    Private m_layout As ItemLayout

End Class
```

[image: Property Window]

**Designer file**

```vb
Me.UiListBox1.StateDisabled.Background.Selected = System.Drawing.Color.Red
```

Comment: Thankyou for the example, but I don't understood how to use it at all, how is supposed that I could update the values at run time? for example I can't do this: `UiListBox1.StateEnabled.Background.Selected = Color.Black`, I'm not understanding how to implement a `Setter` in that way, also, when a property is updated I should invalidate the control (I'm doing that from the `Setter` in the code example that I've provided above), but from those classes I can't acces to the base class to invalidate, could you extend the example, please?

Comment: This is what I've tried with any result:     `Public Property StateEnabled() As ItemLayout
        Get
            Return Me.m_stateEnabled
        End Get
        Set(value As ItemLayout)
            Me.m_stateEnabled = value
             MyBase.Invalidate
            MyBase.Visible = False ' just trying to set a random control's property
        End Set
    End Property`

Answer (score 3):

A `TypeConverter` is not as scary as it sounds:  First, the ListBox property declarations:

```vb
Public Class ListBoxEx
    Inherits ListBox

    <Browsable(True), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always),
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
    Public Property SelectedItemColor As ItemStateColors

    <Browsable(True), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always),
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content),
    DefaultValue(-1)>
    Public Property UnSelectedItemColor As ItemStateColors

    Public Sub New()
        ' they are Objects, be sure to instance them!
        ' VERY important!
        SelectedItemColor = New ItemStateColors
        UnSelectedItemColor = New ItemStateColors

    End Sub

end class
```

Next define your `ItemStateColors` class:

```vb
<TypeConverter(GetType(ItemStateConverter))>
Public Class ItemStateColors

    <Browsable(True), NotifyParentProperty(True),
    EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), DefaultValue(GetType(Color), "")>
    Public Property EnabledBackColor As Color

    <Browsable(True), NotifyParentProperty(True),
    EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), DefaultValue(GetType(Color), "")>
    Public Property DisabledBackColor As Color

    Public Sub New()
        ' default values, if any
        EnabledBackColor = SystemColors.Window
        DisabledBackColor = SystemColors.Control
    End Sub

End Class
```

Each of your `ItemState` properties is an instance of this class.  Note that the `Type` includes a `TypeConverter` attribute - this provides the "magic".  Ours will provide the expando capability AND translates the contents for display in the property grid(s):

```vb
Public Class ItemStateConverter
    Inherits ExpandableObjectConverter

    Public Overrides Function ConvertTo(context As ITypeDescriptorContext,
                               culture As Globalization.CultureInfo,
                               value As Object, destinationType As Type) As Object

        If destinationType Is GetType(String) Then
            Dim item As ItemStateColors = CType(value, ItemStateColors)

            ' ToDo: decide the format of collapsed info            
            Return String.Format("{0}, {1}", item.EnabledBackColor.ToString,
                                 item.DisabledBackColor.ToString)

        End If

        Return MyBase.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType)
    End Function

End Class
```

The `Component` method is simpler to implement, but a `TypeConverter` allows you to control what displays when the property is collapsed:

[image]

---

One of the functions a TypeConverter *usually* performs is the code to serialize/deserialize your types for the designer.  That is not needed here because the Type is simply `Color` which VS/NET knows how to do.  What it does do in this instance is:
  - tag the property as Expandable
  - provide the "Summary" info when the property is collapsed

The other thing you would need it for is when you embed one type in another (as in `myControl.StateEnabled.SelectedItem.ForeColor`).  By nesting them so, you will either need a `TypeConverter` or some code solution such as an instance reference (and I can never tell which elements of your questions are must-haves).  VS only knows to drill into the first layer, you would have to provide a `TypeConverter` to drill down to get the color data.  However, `SelectedItem`, `DeselectedItem` and `ReadOnlyItem` could all use the same `TypeConverter`.

[image]

The Foo Type which inherits from Component, also supplies an empty drop down.

See also:

[ExpandableObjectConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.expandableobjectconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)
[How to: Implement a Type Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

Final note: all your Prop Setters should be testing the value passed and rejecting `Color.Transparent`.

Comment: I seen this answer too late, I will try it, thankyou!

Comment: I wonder if you could explain how you added in the image the "SelectedItemColor" into the "Electro" group, I can''t see the way to do that

Answer (score 1):

Does the `[Category]` attribute work for that?

[Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4448/Customized-display-of-collection-data-in-a-Propert)

Comment: Thanks but the Category attribute only works if the properties are sorted by category (Categorized), not when them are sorted alphabetically in the property grid.

Comment: The example that you've provided explains a thing that is totally different from what you've suggested, and it seems extremelly hard to implement a thing like that, in my oppinion does not seems that the krypton's image that I've shared in my question uses a collection data to create the groups because it does not provides any button to edit a collection content like the figure 5 of the example that you've provided, then I really hope that it could be done easier. Thanks for your answer.