# How to implement a StringFormat in a property grid?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, class, user-controls

> SCENARIO

I've sub-classed a control and I would like to add an `StringFormat` expandable group in the control's property grid to set its values at design time.

> PROBLEM

I'm unable to properly add the StringFormat properties into the property grid, this is what I get:

[image]

> QUESTION

Which is the simplest way to implement an `StringFormat` into a `PropertyGrid`?

> CODE

I've tried the suggestion of @Plutonix answer here: [Create an expandable group in a property grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378606/create-an-expandable-group-in-a-property-grid) (sure I'm doing something wrong)

I preffer to avoid a `TypeConverter` usage in case of this could be done in a simpler way, because I'm not sure whether this implementation needs this kind of headache.

```
Public Class MyControl: Inherits ListBox

    Public Property MyProperty As MyStringFormat = New MyStringFormat

End Class

<TypeConverter(GetType(StringFormatConverter))>
Public Class MyStringFormat

    <Browsable(True)>
    <NotifyParentProperty(True)>
    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)>
    Public Property myStringFormat As StringFormat

    Public Sub New()
        ' default values, if any
        myStringFormat = New StringFormat
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class StringFormatConverter : Inherits ExpandableObjectConverter

    Public Overrides Function ConvertTo(context As ITypeDescriptorContext,
                                        culture As Globalization.CultureInfo,
                                        value As Object,
                                        destinationType As Type) As Object

        Return MyBase.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType)

    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Can you make your example a little less abstract?  It doesnt look like you need an expandableconverter for one thing, and your converter isnt doing anything.  I am not sure it would be needed as most converters for a prop grid are ToString and FromString.  I'm trying to work out what exactly you are after - a string format mask or format flags?

Comment: Thanks for comment. I expected that maybe inheriting the needed class (or something else) I could add at once all the property members of a `StringFormat` Class inside a group into the Grid without more effort,'cause If I need to implement it manually creating each property per separated one by one then I already can do that by myself,I'm asking if is possibly to do it dynamically,but If implementing the entire `StringFormat` class properties at once into the grid is more difficult than what it seems then these are the props that more I need: `Alignment,FormatFlags,LineInputAlignment,Trimming`

Comment: Ok, so you could make it an expando containing those 4 props. There isnt a TypeConverter or UITypeEditor defined for StringFormat, so you need to write your own class (besides it is a sealed class).  But since FormatFlags is a bitwise Enum, you'll probably have to implement a UITypeEditor for it.  (I assume LineInputAlignment == LineAlignment).

Comment: by "expando" you will mean this?: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, I never seen that before, lol.

Comment: either a TypeConverter or Inherit Component since your Type will contain 4 things to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on with your earlier adventure, this is all you need:

```vb
' property on the control

<Browsable(True), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always),
DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content),
DefaultValue(-1)>
Public Property TextFormating As TextFormat

' be sure to instance it!
' TextFormating = New TextFormat
```

Using the Component approach:

```vb
Public Class TextFormat
    Inherits Component

    <Browsable(True), NotifyParentProperty(True),
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible),
    EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), DefaultValue(-1)>
    Public Property Alignment As StringAlignment

    <Browsable(True), NotifyParentProperty(True),
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible),
    EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), DefaultValue(-1)>
    Public Property LineAlignent As StringAlignment

    <Browsable(True), NotifyParentProperty(True),
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible),
    EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), DefaultValue(-1)>
    Public Property Trimming As StringTrimming

    <Browsable(True), NotifyParentProperty(True),
    Editor(GetType(UIEnumEditor), GetType(UITypeEditor)),
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible),
    EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), DefaultValue(-1)>
    Public Property FormatFlags As StringFormatFlags

End Class
```

Add whatever other properties you want.  You can inherit because it is a sealed class, also it doesnt have all the attributes you require.  You wont like the default behavior of the `StringFormatFlags` property; and if you think a TypeConverter is a headache, you are in for a treat!

[image]

---

Since `StringFormatFlags` is a Flag Enum, you will likely want to pick and combine several at a time.  The default UITypeEditor though is a DropDown, but we want a DropDownCheckList.  For this, we need a custom UITypeEditor.  These are not as scary as they sounds, but there is also no need to recreate the wheel:

The [Enhanced CollectionEditor Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718006/Enhanced-CollectionEditor-Framework) article on CodeProject is a collection editor framework which also includes a EnumTypeEditor (scroll to the end of the article where it is mentioned in passing).  In about the middle of the article is a brief primer on `TypeConverters` as well.

To use it:
- download the file and include the DLL in your project
- then (re)decorate your `TextFormat.TextFormatFlags` property:

```vb
<Editor(GetType(UIEnumEditor), GetType(UITypeEditor)),
Browsable(True), NotifyParentProperty(True),
DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible),
EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), DefaultValue(0)>
Public Property TextFormatFlags As StringFormatFlags
```

(Note the added `UIEnumEditor` attribute).

The article and demo shows how to inherit the base editor to customize a few things.  One thing it will do is use `Descriptions` rather than the Enum Name in the list, if they exist and if you want.  That's it, 2 steps and you can check off which flags to combine:

[image]

You dont need a TypeConverter for this one because combining 4 properties into one string doesnt make much sense.  As before, it will still have the empty/extra drop down when your Type inherits Component.

Comment: sorry for my next fast and maybe irrelevant question, but if you could give a short answer: a typeconverter is what I need to FULLY remove the summary info (seen in property grid) from a class inherited from Component class? or it only works with expandoObject?

Comment: The above has no summary *because* I skipped the TypeConverter as described in the last para.  You will get *properties* displaying content because they have to show what they hold.

Comment: yes.. but I ask it because other of my questions where you answered and mentioned that, then, If I want to FULLY remove a summary info instead of displaying the namespace by default, could you clarify if what I need to use is a TypeConverter, or maybe I could use an attribute flag? I realized too much questions today about user controls, if you could clarify that here in a comment thankyou, because my Component classes shows the namespace in the summary info, is ugly for me.

Comment: oh! you mean the Type Names - let me look at the other answer