# Remove TypeNames from property grid expandable group?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, class, user-controls

> PROBLEM

The property groups of my custom user controls displays the type names like this:

[image]

> QUESTION

How them could be removed?

I expect the same result as any other random (and professional) user control like for example the krypton toolset, which does not displays garbage:

[image]

> CODE

This is a code example of how I'm decorating the property grid:

```
Public Class ElektroListBox : Inherits ListBox

    <Category("Appearance")>
    <Description("Enabled state.")>
    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
    Public ReadOnly Property StateEnabled() As StateLayout
        Get
            Return Me.stateEnabled1
        End Get
    End Property
    Private ReadOnly stateEnabled1 As StateLayout

    Public Sub New()
        Me.stateEnabled1 = New StateLayout(Me)
    End Sub

End Class

<ToolboxItem(False)>
Public Class StateLayout : Inherits Component

    <Category("Appearance")>
    <Description("The item foreground.")>
    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
    Public ReadOnly Property Items As ItemLayout
        Get
            Return Me.items1
        End Get
    End Property
    Private ReadOnly items1 As ItemLayout

    Public Sub New(ByVal listBox As ElektroListBox)
        Me.items1 = New ItemLayout(listBox1)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I bet if you look at Krypton.StateCommon in Object Browser, it does not inherit Component.  Component is swell for some of the things it can do for you, but it also comes with a price.

Comment: The property inherits from custom types that inherits from other krypton custom types, and finally the main type inherits from System.Object.

Comment: `System.Object` means a class not inheriting from Component. Component handles things for you like naming and serialization, but that expediency comes with a cost. With Types nested 4 deep your thing is also pretty complex.

Comment: Using `ExpandableObjectConverter` is not as hard as it seems once you get it: http://i.imgur.com/za8Dr3s.jpg (that took 20 mins to do using some code from before and a new TypeConverter).  Plus you could get away from your grouping types needing a reference to the host control (which means they are inexorably tied to that control).

Comment: Thanks @Plutonix, then, if I understood good, If I want to do this with the customization that I want I should rewrite all the code to remove the `Component` classes and 'translate' that classes into `ExpandoObject` classes? plus finally using a `TypeConverter` on those `ExpandoObject` classes to customize (or fully remove, as i want) the info shown in the property grid. I'm right? I'm a little bit lost.

Comment: If you are composing an answer about this issue then I would like to ask if you can do a fast check in the (almost) complete usercontrol source: http://pastebin.com/me06s6xE only to see that once implemented the Component classes for me is a pain to change it all again to other kind of implementation, and maybe again in the future do the same?, I need to be secure of what kind of implementation is what I really need to accomplish the propertygrid's customization features because is a lot of work be writting and rewritting implementations.

Comment: Sorry, I would not do it that way at all.  I understand your frustration over reworking things, but you made a choice [back here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27378606/1070452) with the TypeNames on full display in one and not the other.  You could try to apply a TypeConverter to the Component things, but it is overkill.  Fast - Good - Cheap: pick two.

Comment: No problem!. Just to clarify: My choice was based on my understanding, I mean that I still don't know how to implement a group of properties like the picture of your comment above, I understand how to implement a group, but not a group inside other group as your picture using Typeconverters, then I've used a Component class since this is very easy just I need to append the inheritance on the class name and add the props inside the class, is any dificult once I understood how it works. Ofcourse the same will happen once I can understand how it works the Expando & TypeConv. for what I need. thx!

Comment: I would strongly suggest you abandon the nested sub groups thing.  To do that you either need to use Component and live with the ugly TypeNames *or* write a full blown TypeConverter with calls the TypeConverter for the sub things which calls the TypeCOnverter for its sub items...and all for what, collapsing a set of 2 properties?  I'll check if a TypeConverter on a Compoent thing will work

Comment: Please, check it, it can be a great relief

Comment: Yes, it works.  But know this:  you started with Component so that you would not have to write a TypeCOnverter.  Now, you are considering **adding** a TypeConverter to overcome a shortcoming of that decision.  The **only** way that makes sense is to irrationally cling to collapsing "FG+BG" to "items".  Adding the simple TypeConverter in the aswer and removing `Inherits Component` makes more sense **and** makes your control much less complex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see throughout this series of questions is that you are adding complexity to an already complex task (customizing a control) then trying to implement it in the easiest way possible.  That rarely ends well for me.

#### Do Nothing Classes

Take for instance, your Items/ItemLayout class.  It does nothing and simply exists to collapse 2 lonely things.  It is just as valid (and much easier) to present them as properties of the ItemState.  Each thing *is* just one property of the Style/StateLayout:

```
[+] StateEnabled
  [-] Cursor
  [-] ForeColor
  [-] BackColor
```

If each of **those** also had several sub-properties, apparently like your Krypton tools, then maybe I would consider it.  What I mean is that collapsing BG+FG to Item saves only one line.

#### Easy vs Powerful

The collapsable thing *can* be provided by a Type which inherits from Component.  But a `TypeConverter` inheriting from `ExpandableObjectConverter` is precisely intended for collapsing properties.  A simpler model which does most of what you want; starting with the control class property:

```
<Browsable(True), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always),
DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
Public Property StateEnabled As ItemState
```

The entire state class:

```
<TypeConverter(GetType(ItemStateConverter))>
Public Class ItemState
    Inherits ExpandableObjectConverter

    <Browsable(True), NotifyParentProperty(True),
    EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), DefaultValue(GetType(Color), "")>
    Public Property BackColor As Color

    <Browsable(True), NotifyParentProperty(True),
    EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), DefaultValue(GetType(Color), "")>
    Public Property ForeColor As Color

    <Browsable(True), NotifyParentProperty(True),
    EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), DefaultValue(-1)>
    Public Property Pointer As Cursor

    ' serializer requires a simple ctor
    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    ' see note
    Public Sub New(fg As Color, bg As Color)
        ' default values, if any
        BackColor = bg
        ForeColor = fg
        Pointer = Cursors.Default
    End Sub

End Class
```

The parameterized ctor allows you to create the type with applicable default values:

```
Public Sub New          ' control ctor
   StateEnabled = New ItemState(SystemColors.WindowText, SystemColors.Window)
   ...
```

The Disabled and Selected props could use `.HighlightText` etc for logical starting point rather than Color.Empty.  Your custom control can be added to the form already knowing the existing colors from the user's color theme rather then being required to be set one by one every time.

```
Public Class ItemStateConverter
    Inherits ExpandableObjectConverter

    Public Overrides Function ConvertTo(context As ITypeDescriptorContext,
                               culture As Globalization.CultureInfo,
                               value As Object, destinationType As Type) As Object

        ' need to return something to prevent the
        ' TypeName from displaying.

        If destinationType Is GetType(String) Then
            ' we could provide a Summary of the prop values, but with 3
            ' it gets cluttered:
            '    Dim item As ItemStates = CType(value, ItemStates)

            '    ' ToDo decide the format of collapsed info
            '    Return String.Format("{0}", item.SelectedItem.ForeColor.ToString)

            Return ""
        End If

        Return MyBase.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType)
    End Function

End Class
```

**Thats all.**  Depending on the type, your TypeConverter will be used by VS to provide designer serialization - it is not just styling text for the Props Window.  One reason to `Inherit Component` is to avoid that.  However, what is being serialized here is just a `Color` which VS can handle quite well!

The main things we want from *this* `TypeConverter` is the Summary/Name override and Property collapsing provided by `ExpandableObjectConverter`.  The above is quite literally all I had to add to a previous answer to get to this:

[image]

Note that much of this simplicity goes out the window if you nest things as you have them now.  VS will not/cannot drill into subItems to serialize them which means you'd have to write a full TypeConverter.  For that, I think the `StateLayout` TypeConverter would have to call the TypeConverter for each LayoutItem in the course of creating an `InstanceDescriptor`.

Designer code for the above:

```
Me.ListBoxEx1.StateEnabled.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window
Me.ListBoxEx1.StateEnabled.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText
Me.ListBoxEx1.StateEnabled.Pointer = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default
```

#### Misc

I am not sure why your ItemLayout thing is ReadOnly.  It seems counterproductive:
a) It requires the helper types to have a reference to the control, adds code and complexity
b) It reduces functionality

If you think of these things as `StyleSets`, apps using the control could allow the user or developer to define styles, save them and apply them to a control.  The ReadOnly property prevents that.

- All your Color based Prop Setters ought to be checking for `Color.Transparent` and that is likely to not work too well.  This means they cant really be auto-implement except for illustrative purposes.
- The NotifyParent attribute aids in sub items notifying the parent Type that it has changed.  This is simpler than a reference to the host control.

One more way to implement this is, which may provide a middle ground:

- Implement a `States` collection property on the control
- Seed it with your Enabled, Disabled and ReadOnly Types
- This will collapse them all into one property and let them edit the collection via the standard collection editor and prop grid.
- The only "trick" would be in disabling the Add button, but you should already have the tool for that.
- Alternatively, let them define however many they want and simply map certain ones to the `ReadOnlyStyeSet` property.

Comment: (Miscellaneous:) I'm using Telerik JustCode extension in VS that helps me to fix my name conventions fails and related things, this extension is which tells me that the properties should be declared as readonly and be initialized from the constructor, I don't understand it at all but I confide in my Telerik's virtual teacher... lol. As always you've provided a lot of information, this will not be my last comment, I need to see and try the things you've explained before mark it as accepted, thanks again.